Water is coming up from my vinyl flooring, near the toilet and across the bathroom floor in my new home. Does my flooring need to be ripped up?
This is a new house, only 4 years old with no basement. I found a lot of water coming up from my vinyl flooring and thought that it was from too much water washing the floor.
Now I found it a second time weeks later. I will replace the toilet's wax seal. Is there anything else I can do? I can see that it's traveled under the floor and causing the vinyl planks to be lifted. Do they all have to be ripped out?

What is your subfloor—wood(ish) or concrete?

If it is a floating type flooring, removing them carefully to dry out the floor will help.  Once all dry, can then put them back down.

Beware that it might not be the toilet.  When we moved in we had some vinyl plank flooring get messed up--the culprit was when they installed the tap for the reverse osmosis unit they didn't tighten it quite enough.  Slow leak, only discovered because the water caused the layer laid down underneath to level it adequately to distort.  At no point did we see water until we went looking.

Is there a crawl space or is the floor in direct contact with the ground?

Unfortunately, yes the flooring needs to be taken up and the water removed.
Because the flooring is resistant or impervious it will not allow the water under it to be quickly evaporated.  If left too long the water could cause more serious problems.
As suggested by others, if the flooring is carefully removed it can be laid back down.  Once that is done, I seal the flooring around the toilet ring, so water cannot get under it. I like to use polyurethane caulk, but silicone can work as well.
This may be something that can get expensive enough, if you are hiring others, to consult your insurance company.

Hopefully, you have more than one bathroom because this is a two step, maybe more, solution. After removing the toilet, inspect the flooring. You'll have to pull up the lifted planks and check for moisture. Keep pulling up planks until you find them securely adhering to your subfloor. Water can deteriorate the adhesive that attaches the planks so you want to ensure you have a solid flooring. You'll have to totally dry out the area and check for mold,rot and damage. If the planks you removed are in good shape, you can re-install them using the proper adhesive or installation techniques. If they are not salvageable, you'll need to look for matching planks or redo the entire floor. Once that is completed, install your new wax ring and toilet.

The main purpose of the wax seal is to block gases from the sewer. In normal cases, even if it isn't sealing perfectly you should not be getting water on your floor, as the water goes straight into the waste stack with some velocity. This seal isn’t likely to be the issue.
At any rate it's reasonably easy to disconnect the toilet and lift it off to inspect what's going on.
While you have it off, check a few things:

Take a gallon bucket of water and pour it quickly into the drain. Does the water flow out completely? If not, the drain may be clogged.

This could be due to a badly-routed waste pipe (improper slope, venting etc.), or someone in your household flushing stuff that they ought not to be (like wipes, toys, etc.)

Mounting flange height. If the flange too low (often the case after flooring is installed) you may need to use a taller seal.

One 'hack' is to stack multiple wax seals. But there's a better way: Korky makes a foam rubber seal that can be adjusted for different heights, and it’s reusable (wax seals are not.)

Water intrusion from outside

Look for water coming from other places, like the shower pan (this could be the actual problem, as improper moisture barrier installation is a common defect.) You could also have a failing water line due to bad installation or being pierced by a drywall or trim nail. Check the toilet feed line since that's closest.
It is a good idea to take up some of the flooring, to better see what’s going on and to dry things out.
But to be honest, in the big picture saving your flooring is the least of your problems. Continued moisture intrusion will damage your subfloor and framing, which can lead to dry rot, mold and other issues needing expensive repairs down the road.
Do you have a home warranty? This might cover the problems. Your homeowner's insurance might cover this as well.

Look for the source of the water.  And yes, pull up the flooring.
Possible sources include:

Toilets have supply lines coming from a stop valve; stop valves can leak at the shaft (just encountered that personally)
Each plumbing joint can leak
The supply pipe can leak (how old is the plumbing?)
The joint between the toilet tank and base can leak
If you have pets or pests, they could chew on supply lines
The fill valve could stick open or partially open, perhaps intermittently, overflowing the tank
The tank can become dislodged and cocked on the base; does anyone or anything tend to press on it?
Is it clean or dirty water on the floor?  I've dealt with a flood caused by flushed 'flushable' wipes.  Which are 'flushable' in the same sense that stuffed toys and the TV remote is:  they will go down the toilet into your septic pipes; that is NOT the same as flowing all the way through into the sewer system.  Once one gets stuck in the pipe for any reason, the next can get caught on that one, and a clog quickly forms.  Followed by e.g. sewage coming up out of a downstairs toilet when an upstairs toilet, sink, etc. is used.

Good luck!
